# How to display default value in select option in Angular form field

Tags: angular

I have a select form field in Angular 6 application and the options are coming in from an array. But the `default value` is not being shown or `selected state`? So far my code is as follows:

```
<select formControlName="category" class="form-select">
    <option *ngFor="let state of category" [value]="state.category">
        {{ state.category }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**ts.file**

```
category = [
    { category: 'Nothing'},
    { category: 'Additional'},
    { category: 'Changing'},
  ];


ngOnInit() {
this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
  category: new FormControl(this.category[0]),
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a default value for ngModel for select like:

```
class AppComponent {
  defaultCateg:string="Additional";
}
```

**html:**

```
<select [ngModel]="defaultCateg">
```

[Here is an examle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frhntl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Check the example

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<select(change)="ChangingValue($event)" [value]='55'>
<option value='50'>50/option>
<option value='55'>55</option>
<option value='60'>60</option>
<option value='70'>70</option>
</select>
```